# Limits are computed underlying (category theory)

Tags: category-theory

I am learning about category theory right now and my Professor always uses the phrase: "this limit is computed underlying". (We are dealing with the categories like sets, abelian groups etc.). I would like a rigorous definition of this if possible. Any help is apprechiated.

Comment: I think you meant, limits are computed on the underlying set.

Comment: This is related to the fact that $U:\mathsf{Grp}\to\mathsf{Set}$ is continuous (as it is a right adjoint) so any limit of a diagram of groups must also be a limit of the ‘underlying’ diagram of sets. However that is not sufficient to show that $\mathsf{Grp}$ actually has all limits.

Comment: How much do you know category theory?

Comment: Why not just ask your professor?

Comment: @FShrik Yeah thats what he meant for sure. I dont know about continuous functors to be honest:/ But i do know what a right adjoint is.

Comment: @Nakayama I know the basics. I have seen limits, colimits, adjoints, equivalences of categories and the basic proofs that go with these contructions. Other than that im quite inexperienced.